# javascript array display elements with a comma between elements. How do I change the comma to a dash

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I feel that question is silly but I'm curious about how do I do that.
I have an array that I display in a page built with Svelte. The array is simple:

```
let veggie = ["Lettuce", "Tomoato", "Mayo"]
```

Now when I display it, I use an each block:

```
{#each veggie as item}
 {item} |
{/each}
```

This display it like so -of course- :

```
Lettuce,|Tomato,|Mayo|
```

How do I get rid of the comma - "," - and replace it with the | or any other character?

I tried the use map and add space before and after but the comma persisted. I'm not a js expert so I decided to seek the help of some js ninja outthere. Hopefully, the comma could be defeated. This is my map fn:

```
let newveggie = veggie.map((el)=>{ return "  " + el + "  "
```

I could leave the array element displayed with a comma - no one will die - but I love to challenge myself. Is there a solution? If yes, please share it with me.

Comment: There must be something else wrong, because the original code with a simple each you post does work, it does not display a comma.

Comment: I can confirm Stephane's comment. Copy-pasted the above code into the Svelte REPL (https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world) and did not see a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure svelte simple implementaion :

```
<script>
  let veggie = ["Lettuce", "Tomoato", "Mayo"]
</script>

{#each veggie as item, index}
  { index == veggie.length-1 ? item : `${item} | `}
{/each}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ea0408c617da490683aa4dc5110512ad?version=3.38.2)

Comment: Thank you. What is the $ for? The array is not a store. It's working and I accepted it as the answer as it 's in svelte but I don't understand the code. Would you mind to expxlain it?

Comment: The ‘${expression} string‘ syntax is just standard JavaScript, (it's called template string litteral and has been introduced in the ES6 version of the language), it allows you to mix string content with js expressions in the same block without being too hacky. This is another use case where $ is related to neither svelte nor jQuery but is just plain js :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not a svelte guy . But posting some pure JavaScript solution .

```
let string = "" ;
let customSeparator = "|" ;
let veggie = ["Lettuce", "Tomoato", "Mayo"] ;
 veggie.forEach((elm)=>{
   string = string + customSeparator + elm
 })

console.log(string) ;

//another Method

const aStirng = veggie.join(customSeparator)

console.log(aStirng) ;
```

Comment: Thank you. Excellent answer. More than one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this is what you looking, but you can try with

```
veggie.join("-")
```